# reading all events from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am sending events to google analytics from my web app.  On the "Events" under "Reports" in google analytics, I can only look at the events from active users or events from the last 30 mins.  I want to be able to look at all the events that occurred in the past.  Is there a way to retrieve this data?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under BEHAVIOR > Events > Top Events, select the date range you want in the top right.

[image]

Comment: Do I have to wait some time before the events show up under BEHAVIOR -> Top Events ?  I see the events under REAL-TIME -> Events-> Events(last 30 mins) but I don't see the same events under BEHAVIOR.

Thanks